# ANSI colors in C and ncurses

Tags: c, colors, ncurses, ansi-escape

I know I can do the `attron` and `attroff` with the color I choose to, however, I would like to know if it's possible to do it with the ANSI colour escape codes within ncurses:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
   initscr();
   char *s2 = NULL;
   const char *s1 = "World";
   int n = 10; 

   // What would be a good way to colour %d?
   // seems it is not safe to us the ANSI color escape in here...
   s2 = malloc (snprintf (NULL, 0, "Hello %s \033[22;31m%d", s1, n) + 2); 
   sprintf (s2, "Hello %s \033[22;31m%d", s1, n); 
   printw("%s", s2);
   refresh();
   getch();
   endwin();

   return 0;
}
```

Linking with `-lncurses`

a regular `printf("\033[22;31mHello, World!\n");` in a non-ncurses program works.

Comment: @schneiderfelipe This old question doesn't mention anything about _why_ OP wants this. It looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Why do you want this? What is the real goal that you can't achieve with curses alone?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for asking! I'm currently writing a TUI framework based on curses (https://github.com/schneiderfelipe/kay). It translates ANSI escape sequences into curses calls. Answers to this question might help me with this project.

Comment: Thanks, but .. why is the old framework a guideline? Couldn't you have gone ... either way?

Comment: What do you mean by "old framework"? ANSI escape sequences? I like the idea that it's simply a string, making it very easy to expand on a small core library.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're probably straying into dangerous territory there. Curses will almost certainly track character positions based on output characters and, since it provides its own colour handling, it probably won't detect ANSI escape sequences as well.

If you're after a possible way to allow the ANSI escape sequences in your strings, then one way (kludge though it is) would be to intercept the string and modify it. Have a helper function like `myPrintW()` which takes a string and breaks it down, something like (pseudo-code):

```
def myPrintW(s as copy):
    while s not empty:
        p = position of first ansi-sequence in s
        if p == NULL exit while
        printw first p characters of s
        remove the first p characters from s

        decode ansi-sequence at start of s
        issue relevant attron/off for that ansi-sequence
        remove ansi-sequence from start of s

    endwhile
    output s though it may be empty
enddef
```

This would basically break down the string into normal character sequences and ansi-sequences and you'd process each separately.

It would require a lookup table (or smarts if you need to handle ANSI sequences with arbitrary parameters) in order to translate the sequences into the desired `attron/off` calls.

Comment: Yes I did try, but it did not work. I'm wondering, what would be a good way of doing the above (I updated my sample code)

Comment: I like the approach, however, I'm wondering if the lookup table is necessary?

Comment: If you can find a _formula_ for converting the ANSI sequence into a colorpair, that would be better. But, since I don't _know_ exactly what COLOR_PAIR(a,b) will do on a general implementation, it's probably safer to use a lookup.

Comment: Hey, this solution pairs really well with the links found in [@Ciro Santilli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210354/4039050). It seems that the way to go is writing a parser. @paxdiablo You got the bounty 

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It all depends on what kind of software or firmware is listening to the program's output.  For V3.3 MSDOS, no, it won't work unless the device driver ansi.sys is loaded.

Modern terminal windows tend to have [ANSI x3.64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_X3.64) semantics, so those escape sequences will often work.  But don't expect too much:  extra wide and extra high characters are notoriously poorly supported.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be too safe integrating ANSI on `ncurses`. You want to use `attron/off` calls and perhaps split the string into `%s` and `%d`. For > 2 conversions, you need to implement your own `printw`

Answer (score 1):

2008 mailing list thread discussing this: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2008-11/msg00026.html

The possibilities raised were to:

- create a parser for ANSI escape codes (WONTFIX in source). Mutt and Screen implement this: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2008-11/msg00028.html
- create a terminfo entry: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2008-11/msg00029.html