# Handle escape sequences with ncurses? Does printf handle escape sequences?

Tags: c, printf, ncurses, ansi-escape

My program read some text data from network, something like:
`Hello \033[1;34mworld\033[0m and bla bla bla!!!\n"`.
When program output this string using prinf, the word "world" is blue. But when I'm using ncurses interface with wprintw or addch, I see the original string with escape sequences.
Does it mean that printf handle escape sequences or not?
What is the best way handle escape sequences with ncurses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373690/ansi-colors-in-c-and-ncurses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your terminal handles the escape sequences. The phenomenon you're seeing comes from the fact that ncurses' whole purpose is to keep track of the intended terminal contents and be able to repaint it, and as part of doing this it strips any escape sequences. It might provide an alternative function to *interpret* them and apply them to its own image of what the terminal should contain, but otherwise you'll have to do this job yourself...

Comment: Thank you!
So, does it correct that I've two ways:
1. Use alternative function
2. Handle in program by myself

Comment: Can you explain the first choice in more details. Should I patch ncurses library for that or has is some hooks for that? And If I use the second way, should I check TERM environment variable from remote side which send data to me or should I use another way to determine terminal type on remote side. And when I determine terminal type, I suppose I should use terminfo database to clarify how to interpret escape sequences, does it correct?

Comment: You definitely should not patch ncurses. If it doesn't have a function that accepts strings with color escapes in them, you need to write the code to process the string with color escapes and convert it into a series of ncurses calls.