# How to display pre-colored string with curses?

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I'm writing a curses program in Python. I'm a beginner of curses but I've used terminal control sequences for colored output.

Now there's some code snippets to print inside the window, I'd like them be syntax highlighted, and it's better done with libraries like pygments, which outputs highlighted code with control sequences.

Initially I feed pygments output directly to `window.addstr()`, but it is turned out that the control sequences is escaped and the whole highlighted string is printed on the screen (just like this: https://too-young.me/web/repos/curses-highlight.png). How can I display it directly with curses, just like `cat`?

Comment: What modules are you using? What code is escaped? Please include snippet if possible, your question is really unspecific.

Comment: @VisgeanSkeloru I'm sorry for the unclear. You can try https://gist.github.com/secondwtq/189c415b09c2fa3ef757

Comment: Check this pip module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked several times, with the same answer: you could write a parser to do this.  curses (Python or not) is a high-level interface, with some low-level functions for special tweaking.  The high-level interface assumes that strings are all **data** to be displayed.  The [`addch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters) manpage goes into some detail explaining that.  If you use the low-level functions (such as [putp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.putp)), the high-level curses calls do not know what has been displayed.

For related discussion:

- [How to use ANSI escape codes inside mvwprintw in ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464023/how-to-use-ansi-escape-codes-inside-mvwprintw-in-ncurses)
- [Comment on Parsing ANSI color escape sequences](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=215785)
- [Handle escape sequences with ncurses? Does printf handle escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212070/handle-escape-sequences-with-ncurses-does-printf-handle-escape-sequences)

It is not suitable as an extension to ncurses for example because:

- curses *produces* escape sequences, but for a wide variety of devices (which may not be "ANSI color escapes").
- ncurses (see the FAQ *[Why aren't my bugs being fixed?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#backlog)*) does not provide it as an extension because a parser of this type would not rely upon any of ncurses' internals.

Comment: So curses is not designed for this purpose. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: yes - but you can make applications which do this, that use curses to display the result

Answer (score 5):

There's the "[culour](https://github.com/spellr/culour)" python module which does exactly that.

Install it using `pip install culour`, and then you can use it to print pre-colored strings:

```
import culour
culour.addstr(window, colored_string)
```

This will print the string colored in your window.

Comment: Yes but in that module is circular import and it becomes impossible to import it

Comment: Fixed  You can upgrade and use

Comment: /culour.py", line 41, in _color_str_to_color_pair
    fg = TERMINAL_COLOR_TO_CURSES[color]
KeyError: '[107'

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub there is a free to use, study, modify and re-distribute High Level GUI library, at "https://github.com/rigordo959/tsWxGTUI_PyVx_Repository".

It is implemented in Python 2x & 3x using the "curses" Low Level GUI package. The Linux nCurses implementation has typically replaced the original Unix Curses implementation.

Your application programs can be programmed using a character-mode subset of the pixel-mode "wxPython" High Level GUI API. It supports displays with keyboard and mouse input and various terminal emulators including the color xterms (8-color with 64-color pairs and 16-color with 256-color pairs) and non-color vt100/vt220.

Curses enables you to colorize text strings by inserting an attribute (for color, underline, bold, reverse etc.) token before the text and one to restore the previous attribute after the text. For example:

```
sampleWindow.attron(curses.A_REVERSE | 
                    curses.color_pair(color_pair_number))
sampleWindow.addstr(begin_y + 3,
                    begin_x + 48,
                    '        ')
sampleWindow.attroff(curses.A_REVERSE |
                     curses.color_pair(color_pair_number))
```