# Color pass-through in urwid or curses

Tags: python, curses, urwid

I would like to write a wrapper around `git log`, somewhat similar to `gitk` but on a terminal.

I thought this should be easy because `git log` already formats the output, all I need to do is put it in a list view where I can select a commit.

However, both urwid and curses mess up the color codes which `git log` is using.
I tried to implement a custom urwid widget hoping it might leave the color codes alone but it does not behave any different.

I considered to move the coloring of the output from `git log` to my wrapper but that's not possible with the `--graph` option.

A direct pass through of colors works with a normal print statement but I don't want to reinvent window management, input handling, recognition of resizing and I don't know what else.

How can I stop urwid or curses to touch the color codes?

---

desired output:
[image]

achieved output:
[image]

MWE:

`model.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

class LogModel():

    encoding = "utf-8"
    cmd = ["git", "log", "--color", "--graph", "--pretty=format:%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset", "--abbrev-commit"]

    def get_lines(self):
        p = subprocess.run(self.cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True, encoding=self.encoding)
        out = p.stdout

        return out.splitlines()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = LogModel()
    for ln in log.get_lines():
        print(ln)
```

(credit for the git log format goes [here](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log))

`main_urwid.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urwid
import model

class MyText(urwid.Widget):

    _sizing = frozenset(['flow'])

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = text.encode("utf-8")

    def render(self, size, focus=False):
        (maxcol,) = size
        return urwid.TextCanvas([self.text], maxcol=maxcol, check_width=False)

    def rows(self, size, focus=False):
        return 1

class LogView(urwid.ListBox):

    def __init__(self, log_model):
        widgets = [self.create_line_widget(ln) for ln in log_model.get_lines()]
        body = urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker(widgets)
        super().__init__(body)

    def create_line_widget(self, ln):
        #return urwid.Text(ln, wrap=urwid.CLIP)
        return MyText(ln)

class App():

    palette = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.view = LogView(model.LogModel())

    def run(self):
        self.loop = urwid.MainLoop(self.view, self.palette,
            unhandled_input=self.unhandled_input)
        self.loop.run()

    def unhandled_input(self, k):
        if k == "q":
            raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = App()
    a.run()
```

`main_curses.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import curses
import model

def main(stdscr):
    log_model = model.LogModel()

    curses.use_default_colors()
    stdscr.clear()

    col = 0
    for row, ln in enumerate(log_model.get_lines()):
        stdscr.addstr(row, col, ln)

    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: For ncurses, set `$TERM` to `vt100` (no color), but git's logs may still send color-escapes (which your curses-example doesn't filter).

Comment: @ThomasDickey thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that does not help. I have set `export TERM=vt100` before running my program (and commented out `curses.use_default_colors()` which then causes an error) but the output is still the same. git still outputs the color codes (as desired) and curses still prints them as text instead of colors (which I would like to change).

Comment: It'd be simpler to answer as two questions.  For curses, this is a duplicate, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189434/how-to-display-pre-colored-string-with-curses/30202083#30202083).

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks for pointing me to those answers. I'll need some more time to look into it but I think that answers my question.