# Print ansi-formatted text in curses

Tags: python, curses

I have some ansi-formatted text in python. I want to print it in curses.
When I do print it:

```
^[[34mprint^[[39;49;00m ^[[39;49;00m^[[33m'^[[39;49;00m^[[33mhi^[[39;49;00m^[[33m'^[[39;49;00m
```

I'm using the following to setup curses:

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.raw(True)
curses.start_color()
curses.use_default_colors()
stdscr.keypad(1)
```

Comment: How can I print it to curses?

Comment: how are you trying to print it? the code snippet you posted is missing that part.

Comment: This answers your question: [ANSI colors in C and ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373690/ansi-colors-in-c-and-ncurses)