# How to output terminal control chars in ncurses?

Tags: terminal, ncurses

I have a document with terminal control characters (raw characters, depending on how you name those) embedded to display bold fonts, set colors, etc. `cat` this document works fine. But I want to display this text in a ncurses program retaining its terminal control characters. Do functions like `waddstr` understand terminal control characters? Do I have to parse those characters by myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ANSI escape codes inside mvwprintw in ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464023/how-to-use-ansi-escape-codes-inside-mvwprintw-in-ncurses).  See also [discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2008-11/msg00026.html)

Comment: @ThomasDickey So, should we use matt's code as the demo?