# sending escape sequences to terminal with NCurses

Tags: c, ncurses

so I'm using NCurses for a project and the terminal I'm using it on accepts special escape sequences for custom features like playing audio. The position of the cursor doesn't matter while sending these escape sequences, however when using printf it doesn't get pushed to the output stream. Is there a way to write to bypass ncurses and write to the terminal directly? I heard about possibly restoring the streams and after giving them back to ncurses but that seems hacky.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ANSI escape codes inside mvwprintw in ncurses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464023/how-to-use-ansi-escape-codes-inside-mvwprintw-in-ncurses)

Comment: nope, see my own solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up finding a hacky solution since I only needed the escape codes to be *sent* to the terminal emulator (cursor position & other context didn't matter)

I used fputs to write to STDOUT and then used fflush() to push it to the terminal.

```
fputs("\033]16;2", stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: This defies the whole purpose of using (n)curses in the first place... [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210354/4039050) is a more down-to-earth way of doing this, IMHO.